# Como automatizar una ejecucion PHP y MySql

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo un scritp que eliminado los datos de una agenda 30 días después de ser publicada.

Este es el código.

```
<?php

$sql = "DELETE FROM agenda WHERE ABS(DATEDIFF(fecha, NOW())) >= fechal";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);                                 
$stmt->execute();

?>
```

Lo que quiero hacer y saber es como puedo automatizar esta acción que solo se ejecuta en el listado de agenda y tengo que hacer copiar del código también en el panel general, lo que significa que si el usuario no ingresa al panel o no ve el listado, la acción no se ejecuta y las publicaciones quedan a pesar de los 30 días.

Gracias!

Comment: Te serviria hacer un procedimiento almacenado en la base de datos que se ejecute automaticamente cada dia y borre los datos de una agenda con esa condicion. Tienes acceso a la base de datos?

Comment: Si, se conecta a la base de datos y tengo los datos, pero ese depende del sistema operativo del servidor o no? o se puede hacer con otro lenguaje?

Comment: Si estoy en lo correcto a lo que se refiere tu requerimiento, yo lo que te propongo  es programar en la base de datos ese proceso y que se ejecute automaticamente con la frecuencia que tu necesites

Comment: Entiendo, tu me dices dentro de la misma base de datos?